# An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for <Web Project>.". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I just downloaded Eclipse Luna on my new laptop and as soon as I have created a new Dynamic Web project and try to expand the project in the explorer, I get this error message:

```
"An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for WebProjectTest.".
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

I initially ignored the message, but when I go to add a servlet through the 'create servlet' window and type a name for the class I'm unable to press 'next'.

I have Java 1.7 installed and had no problems at all using Eclipse Juno on my old laptop

Comment: which container? any stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and realized that it was because I had accidentally downloaded the non-J2EE version of Eclipse.  It looks like the plugins and Eclipse itself does not recognize that you're asking it to to J2EE things in a non-J2EE app and will throw mysterious errors and exceptions like this.  My solution was to start over and download the J2EE version of Eclipse and reload the project in that.

I think it might be possible to upgrade a non-J2EE Eclipse by downloading all of the right tools but it is probably simpler to just re-download it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove a descriptor, as far as [servlet 3.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/) spec the web project doesn't required to use web project deployment descriptor. If a descriptor is a main cause of the error then it would solve you first problem. The second problem required some mode details. If the button is disabled it might be an internal error, or restricted behavior of the control. You need to use a stable release to have less bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ive decided to roll back to Eclipse Keplar for now - and am having no issues with that atm.

Comment: Make sure you have right package [downloaded](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar).